Quantum home experiments with few resources
In the introduction of Dirac's book Principles of Quantum Mechanics, it can found the following words:

[...] Suppose we have a beam of light passing through a crystal of tourmaline, which has the property of letting through only light plane-polarized perpendicular to its optic axis. Classical electrodynamics tells us what will happen for any given polarization of the incident beam. If this beam is polarized perpendicular to the optic axis, it will all go through the crystal; if parallel to the axis, none of it will go through; while if polarized at an angle $\alpha$
to the axis, a fraction $\sin 2\alpha$
will go through. How are we to understand these results on a photon basis?

This way to present the property of polarization superposition for light wave and after to  propose it for the photon, made me think that Quantum phenomena are not so far to mundane experience, at least with mild assumptions and considerations. Of course a tourmaline crystal is not something you can just catch in the ground near your house (or it is, depending where you live), and probably is not any tourmaline crystal that exhibit such phenomena, but Dirac made me dream with a homemade PBS.

My question is: Do you know any other quantum experiment that can be done with simple resources?
We can employ Dirac's trick by first think about a light wave experience, and then to ask "How we understand these results on a photon basis?*, but it would be nice to think about experiences that does not rely on it.
I know one (applying Dirac trick) very simple: If you shine a laser on a strand of hair, you will see an interference pattern form behind it. It is the cheapest dual slit I know for sure.
(If someone know, please tell me if the homemade PBS is really possible)
EDIT:
I Found another example, without the photon argument. It is possible to probe the Diamagnetism of water at home, something that, as far as I know, is impossible to explain classically.

The double slit interference supposedly can be seen with everyday items: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXyxnxnWAAQ

As for the diamagnetism thing, you do observe it with stronger magnets. By the Bohr–Van Leeuwen theorem, static magnetic fields in thermal equilibrium are only possible due to quantum mechanics. A bar magnet will do.

@James & others who are voting for the double slit experiment video. Can you please explain which quantum phenomena is shown in this video? To the naive, such as myself, this appears to show classical wave optics phenomena (diffraction).

@antimony I think It fits in the "Dirac's trick" as I mentioned in the post. Imagine we reproduce it with a single photon...

ok i got you, thanks @Ruffolo

Spectral lines are a quantum effect. You need an appropriate light source and a prism or diffraction grating.

The diamagnetism being impossible classically is common belief but overstated. What is impossible is that system of charged particles with zero magnetic moment, obeying Boltzmannian statistics, can't have non-zero macroscopic magnetic moment. But if you allow particles to have magnetic moment, or if you think of systems not described by the Boltzmann distribution (e.g. set of charged particles circling in magnetic field, with non-zero surface current), diamagnetism is present in classical physics.

if optical discs are still a common household item, they can be used as a grating https://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/shivok/_files/documents/SP212_Lab_Ten_ShivokHuddle_Rev42014.pdf

@JánLalinský what you are saying is right but it applies to all kinds of magnetism, not just diamagnetism.

@Mauricio Do you know of classical model of ferromagnetism?

@JánLalinský the Ising model? Langevin model? As you said, you just have to accept the existence of intrinsic magnetic moments.

@Mauricio Yes but I mean without assuming stable magnetic moment, just with charged particles. I know only of diamagnetism, e.g. free electrons moving in circles in magnetic field.

@JánLalinský there isn't per Bohr-Van Leeuwen, the same way diamagnetism does not work either. I mean you could build an Ising model with moments given by charged particles moving in circles if that is allowed.

@JánLalinský actually charges moving in circles is not a model for diamagnetism but for paramagnetism, in first order it couples to the magnetic field not the opposite. The anti-aligment comes either from Lenz law or from precession around the orbit.

@Mauricio free charges moving in circles have magnetic moment opposed to external magnetic field, they are repelled by sources of this field; e.g. they get reflected by strong enough concentration of magnetic field lines, so-called magnetic mirror. Thus they behave diamagnetically.

@JánLalinský I am not sure what you mean. You take the Hamiltonian of a particle in an electromagnetic field and look for the terms linear on $B$ and you will see that the magnetic moment related to its orbital angular momentum couples to the field, thus paramagnetism.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
